# How to get the html code of selected element?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get html code of a child element using following code :

**HTML**

```
<div id="cont">
<img src="http://fakeimg.pl/230x153/555/FFF/?text=1" alt="">
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function() {
  console.log($("#cont").find("img").html());
});
```

I would like to have `<img src="http://fakeimg.pl/230x153/555/FFF/?text=1" alt="">` in my console

But Its returning nothing. I dont know whats wrong. I'm pretty sure I'm making some silly mistake.

Thanks.

**Link to jsBin :** http://jsbin.com/urahos/1/edit

---

**EDIT**

**Correct Answer**

I dont know someone just posted the right answer and removed it.

Following is what I was looking for :

```
$(function(){
  $("#cont").find("img")[0].outerHTML;
});
```

Comment: *"I dont know whats wrong."* `.html` returns the **inner** HTML of an element. An image element cannot have children, so its inner HTML is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
$(function() {
  console.log($("#cont").html());
});
```

You want to read the `.html()` of the `#cont` where the `img` is in.

Comment: This will work only if the img is the only child of `#cont`.

Comment: Yes, but you can't guarantee that the structure is that simple in "real life".

Comment: Totally Agree with @Juhana! I simplified the structure to put focus on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

console.log($("#cont").html())

Answer (score 0):

It would be like this:

```
console.log($("#cont").html())
```

Comment: This is Already answered 3 min ago. No need to have 4 same answers

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function() {
  var result=$("#cont").children('img').attr("src");
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: *"I would like to have `<img src="http://fakeimg.pl/230x153/555/FFF/?text=1" alt="">` in my console"* --- not only the image url.